# highcharts x-axis is displaying the wrong data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

my highcharts code is as follow: pretty much this is always starting from 01, and its displaying january and february

I did look up highcharts documentation I couldn't figure out how to make this thing work the days need to be +1 everytime. meaning if it starts the 5th, it will show 5 6 7 8 9 
based on the number of values in series.
the chart displays total pageviews for each day. anyway you point me in the right direction ?

```
    $('#arpv').highcharts({exporting: { enabled: false } ,
        xAxis: {
              type: 'datetime',     
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%d. '

        },pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 

        },
        yAxis: {
            floor: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Pageviews'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Pagesviews Summary',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
        //    text: 'pageviews over time',
            x: -20
        },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' Pageviews',
                crosshairs: true,
                 formatter: function() {
        var date = new Date(this.x);
        var year = date.getFullYear();


        return '<span style="color:'+this.series.color+'">'+ this.series.name +'</span>: '+ this.y + ' pageviews';
     },
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
                 series: [  { name: 'Pageviews', data: [ 26562,5793,26585,2203,1444,2150,2833,2416,10114,13564,16234,15253,5415,10340,18184,12830,14340,21520,18883,41571,23913,16013,16681,10499,18557,18692,14550,6655,17490,46258,26671,5739,26585,49114,30038,25998,19076,26577,10231,24110 ],pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 } ]


    });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the xAxis config, you are using `pointInterval`, it should be `tickInterval`.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',     
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%d. '

    },
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 
}
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7z5yvd9/).

Answer (score 1):

The [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval) parameter should be placed in the plotOptions.series, not on xAxis.